# Using TDD with MVC Controller actions and ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, attributes, tdd

I am developing using TDD and ASP.Net MVC.

I have a custom ActionFilterAttribute which needs to be applied to certain controller actions and was wondering the best approach to this using TDD.

- Currently the attribute itself has a
  set of unit tests.
- I develop the
  controller action with tests as per
  normal but ignore the case handled by
  the attribute.
- I add a unit test that
  uses relfection to ensure the
  attribute is applied (with correct
  parameters) to the action.

If this a suitable way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it is.

What confuses You? Test that tests if attribute is applied? There is nothing bad with that. Testing actual constructions of code is very useful technique. You can force various conventions too with this approach like naming of classes in particular namespace, existence of public constructors w/o arguments, etc.

Comment: Yes, I guess my question could be rephrased: 'is testing the attribute has been applied (via reflection) acceptable TDD'. I've not tested attributes before so just wanted confirmation there is no other preferred practice. Thanks.